# NHibernate serialization issue - Type 'NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration' is not marked serializable

Tags: nhibernate, serialization

I'm trying to improve the startup time of a C# Winforms application that uses NHibernate by **serializing** the **NHibernate.Cfg.configuration** object (as described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx) but i'm getting the following error when i try and serialize:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
>   : Type 'NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration'
>   in Assembly 'NHibernate,
>   Version=1.2.1.4000, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' is
>   not marked as serializable.

Another stackoverflow post that mentions this is [duplicate object graph and persist back as new in nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663261/duplicate-object-graph-and-persist-back-as-new-in-nhibernate) but unfortunately, taking into account the comments posted there i am still getting the same error.

None of the entities that are included in the **ClassMappings** Collection property of **NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration** object have any reference to **NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration** or the **Session** or **SessionFactory**. In fact, the project in which those entities are included has no reference whatsoever to the project in which my **NHibernateHelper** class is found.

Just to make sure, i have also marked **all** classes with the **[Serializable]** attribute but that hasn't helped either.

Below is my **NHibernateHelper** class and the NHibernate xml configuration:

**NHibernateHelper:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Context;

namespace PurchaseOrder.Data
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A helper class which provides NHibernate session objects on demand.
    /// The class creates a session factory only the first time a client needs a new session.
    /// </summary>
    public class NHibernateHelper
    {
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
        private const string SerializedConfiguration = "configurtion.serialized";

        public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory{
            get{
                if (_sessionFactory == null){
                    var configuration = LoadConfigurationFromFile();

                    if (configuration == null){
                        configuration = new Configuration();
                        configuration.Configure();
                        SaveConfigurationToFile(configuration);
                    }

                    _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
                }
                return _sessionFactory;
            }
        }

        private static Configuration LoadConfigurationFromFile(){
            try{
                using (var file = File.Open(SerializedConfiguration, FileMode.Open)){
                    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                    return bf.Deserialize(file) as Configuration;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                return null;
            }
        }

        private static void SaveConfigurationToFile(Configuration configuration){
            using (var file = File.Open(SerializedConfiguration, FileMode.Create)){
                var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(file, configuration);
            }
        }

        public static ISession OpenSession(){
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        public static ISession GetCurrentSession(){
            return SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        }
    }
}
```

**NHibernate xml configuration:**

```
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=<ServerName>;initial catalog=<DBName>;Integrated Security=SSPI</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread_static</property>
        <mapping assembly="<AssemblyName>" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem is you're using NHibernate 1.2. It's really old (3 years old now), it didn't have a serializable Configuration ([code here](https://github.com/mausch/NHibernate/blob/1.2.1.GA/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Cfg/Configuration.cs)).

Upgrade to NHibernate 2.1.2 or better yet 3.0.